# Filling an array of object without creating a new object everytime

Tags: php

I fill an array with objects in another class like so :

```
    class user{

      public $name;
      public $points;
    } 

    class arrayUser{

      public $array = array();
      public $user = new user;

      public function exemple(){

        $user->name = 'Bob';
        $i = 1;

        while($i <= 3){

          $user->points = $i;
          $array[] = $user;
          $i++;
        }
      }
    }
```

If I do a print_r() of the array I get :

```
array(

  name = 'Bob'
  points = 3

  name = 'Bob'
  points = 3

  name = 'Bob'
  points = 3
)
```

Rather then (this is the result I'm looking for):

```
array(

  name = 'Bob'
  points = 1

  name = 'Bob'
  points = 2

  name = 'Bob'
  points = 3
)
```

Is there a way to make it work without having to instantiate a new user everytime?

Comment: Welcome. The PHP code you posted is invalid, so you should probably fix it first.

Comment: Please show us your _actual_ code, not something that may or may not be truly representative of it.  Also give that actual dump output.

Comment: You need to create a new instance everytime, otherwise it will always point to the same memory address, and then the same values. Or you use a structure like array.

Comment: "without having to instantiate a new user"...why is that such a big problem? Don't fight the language.